# Intersect values on Mysql comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I've a table `PriceList` that has a `VARCHAR` column `tags` where I store a comma separated list of values.
An example of price list is:

| ID | name | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Price list 1 | tag1,tag2 |
| 2 | Price list 2 | tag3,tag4 |

What I want now is to query this table passing a list of tags (comma separated values). A priceList should be selected **only** if **all** of its tags are present in the query.
The tags I pass in the query could be more than the tags defined in the PriceList's tags column.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM PriceList WHERE 'tag2,tag1,tag7' IN/FIND_IN_SET??? (tags)
```

In this example I expect the PriceList ID1 is retrieved because **all** of its tags are included in 'tag2,tag1,tag7' values.

I did not find any useful function in Mysql to accomplish to what I need to do. I know this is not the best design and this is acceptable because PriceList table is really really small (5/10 items).

The only idea that came to my mind is to store tags sorted alphabetically and to see if PriceList's tag column is a substring of my tags list.
What do you think? Do you have some hint?

Comment: fix your normalization now before it's too late.  then this would be a trivial query

Comment: @Randy I see your point and I agree with you, but for the sake of completeness I'd like to see if there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @FaNo_FN I'm using RDS Aurora 2.10 (Mysq 5.7)

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on the following, it splits tags in the PriceList to multiple rows and count the matching rows against the input taglist

```
SELECT a.ID, MAX(a.tags), MAX(a.name)
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.tags, ',', comma_index), ',', -1) AS tag, p.ID, LENGTH(p.tags) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.tags, ',', '')) + 1 AS counts, p.tags, p.name
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS comma_index
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5
    )  a
    JOIN PriceList p
    WHERE a.comma_index <= LENGTH(p.tags) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.tags, ',', '')) + 1
) a 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.tag, 'tag2,tag1,tag7')
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(a.counts)
```

The UNION part is an example, make sure the running numbers are more than the maximum number of tags in the table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb379d/1

But be sure it is not a good design to concat tags while individual tags are still in use, consider to have a table store tags separately.